# On click event not always working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a problem with my JS code. What happens is when I do a mouse click event on a div it always does half of the operations inside it, but the other half only go trough like half of the times.

Here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var currentMousePosition = new MousePosition(0,0);
var positionArray = []


$("html").mousemove(function(event){
    if(currentMousePosition.x != event.pageX || currentMousePosition.y != event.pageY){
        currentMousePosition.x = event.pageX;
        currentMousePosition.y = event.pageY;
        if(positionArray.length<500){
            positionArray.push(new MousePosition(currentMousePosition.x,currentMousePosition.y));
        }
        //$("#array").html(JSON.stringify(positionArray));
        $("#data").html("( "+event.pageX+" , "+event.pageY+" ) - moves: "+positionArray.length);
    }
});

$("#mouse").on("click",function(){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var m1=0;
    var m2=0;
    for(var i=0;i<positionArray.length-2;++i){
        m1=(positionArray[i+1].y-positionArray[i].y)/(positionArray[i+1].x-positionArray[i].x);
        m2=(positionArray[i+2].y-positionArray[i].y)/(positionArray[i+2].x-positionArray[i].x);
        while(m1==m2){
            var p=i+2;
            positionArray.splice(p-1,1);
            m2=(positionArray[p].y-positionArray[i].y)/(positionArray[p].x-positionArray[i].x);
        }
    }
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - start;

    $("#array").html(JSON.stringify(positionArray));
    $("#mouse").html(time);
    $("#data").html("( "+event.pageX+" , "+event.pageY+" ) - moves: "+positionArray.length);
});
```

});

and the corresponding html

```
<button id="mouse">time</button>

<div id="data"></div>
<div id="array"></div>
<div id="time"></div>
```

I know that when I click the #mouse the for loop always goes through. However, those 3 .html updates don't. It's weird, because it works on a 50% chance random base.

I'm a JS newby, am I making any obvious mistake?

Thanks

**Update:**
What this does is detect everytime the mouse moves and save the position in positionArray. When I click the #mouse div it goes through the data and checks for points in a line, and removes those, though the algorithm is not the point here. On click, it is supposed to apply that algorithm (which it does) and to update the text of those #array, #mouse and #date (which it doesn't).

Any clue?

Comment: post the full script. What is `positionArray`?

Comment: your code fails in the middle. JS is interpreter so it goes line by line until it fails. check developer console for errors

Comment: is this correct way to write while loop...And Inside a for loop..?????

Comment: @chandu, there should be no problem at all to write a while loop inside a for loop

Comment: @Banana, thanks for the advice, I didn't even know developer console existed. That totally solved my problem. The problem was that, in some circunstances, an out of range index of postitionArray was being called, which caused the script to crash and not execute the referred tasks. Thanks!